# Keyboard shortcut with 'fn' combination in cinnamon

Tags: cinnamon

My keyboard has several Fn key shortcuts and I can use combinations like Fn+F3 to increase the volume, Fn+F9 to reduce brightness and it works.

There are some combinations that do nothing or are useless, for example: Fn+F5 to search and Fn+F12, to disable the touchpad, and I would like to assign those combinations to a different action.

I tried to add a custom shortcut setting up any of those two combinations, and both are recognized, but don't work.

I tried to set Fn+F12 to open Terminal and it doesn't work, but when I set Super+F12 it works.

Any ideas of why shortcuts with Fn are not working?